Please add a feature to give constructive feedback, guidance to improve posts, and plenty of time for improvement before deleting posts
There is no feedback or guidance given by reviewers in deleting posts, so users cannot improve posts. An important feature of Stack Exchange sites is that questions and answers can be edited, and so can evolve.
I don't know if it's just me, but I find it unpleasant as a user, that an answer I spend a few hours figuring out gets deleted with no feedback, nor tips for improving it. So even though I care about creating a good answer and contributing to the site, I don't see how to improve an answer that is not accepted by the reviewers. This is only my experience with the Math Stack Exchange site.
Thank you!

A post can only be deleted after it is closed.  When a post is closed, reasons are given.  These reasons are generally displayed in a blue banner above the question.  You may find these insufficient, but they are there.

@XanderHenderson see this is the post: https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/2169801  Someone commented "this does not answer the question", but I believe it answers it, and I don't know how to improve it. It would make more sense, to suggest deletion with guidance on how to improve it. So a user would have 6-8 improvements to implement, from all the anonymous reviewers.

Sorry, I cannot find the reasons, where are they?

No reasons are given whatsoever, and it would be easy to implement a feature to require reviewers tips or guidance on improving posts. It is easy to downvote and delete posts, but it does not contribute to improving posts. This is an accessibility, and UX issue, a design feature of the platform that creates unpleasantness.

I just found this, might be relevant:

9: Help Users Recognize, Diagnose, and Recover from Errors
Error messages should be expressed in plain language (no error codes), precisely indicate the problem, and constructively suggest a solution.

https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ten-usability-heuristics/

Having answers deleted is not easy. For instance, answers can't be deleted on the basis of being wrong. An answer is deleted for other reasons, chiefly because a sufficient number of users agreed that "it has severe quality or content issues and it can't be salvaged through editing" or that "it doesn't answer the question". Downvoting answers is not easy either, because the downvoters need to expend their reputation to do so. As is the primary way to make the community aware of a wrong answer, I don't see why those people should be nagged any further, at least by design.

On the matter of "improving somebody else's answer", and what to do by design, answers should be written when they are right, not before. If userA has a problem and userB can't guarantee autonomously the quality of their answer, then they should not answer in the first place, as they might not be in the condition to solve somebody else's problem. If userC has to intervene to explain to userB where they're wrong and suggest a correction, then userC is effectively writing userB's answer, so why shouldn't they solve the original task of helping userA directly, by writing their own answer instead?

@SassatelliGiulio my experience is that I don't know how to edit the post for it not be deleted, or it to be undeleted. In Python programming if you don't use docstrings, comments explaining how a functin works then another programmer might suggest using docstrings. If a comment is redundant, they might suggest that, which you can implement by editing the code. Stack Exchange supports editing of posts even when they are deleted, but I edited many of my posts many times and there is no clear constructive feedback following the edits, which is a design issue.

@SassatelliGiulio answers and questions are made collaboartively here, this is why edits and giving constructive comments are rewarded. In my experience I learn a lot from struggling to create an answer or question, and getting feedback on it. As we know mistakes and imperfection are a good part of the learning and making process, so these should be embraced by the design also. I find it is often not easy to ask mathematics questions, or give answers, but it is important to be able to engage in making questions and answers.

@SassatelliGiulio it seems very easy to skim, and downvote posts. It is probably more difficult to ask mathematics questions, and to spend effort answering a question. While skimming and downvoting doesn't contribute much to good questions and answers, making effort to ask a question, or to answer one does contribute to it. Maybe the question/answer is imperfect, but it can be improved, and it is also easy for someone to suggest improvements, if they are more experienced and really can recognise a good post just by skimming it.

This is an app for people studying mathematics at all levels, so a person with no mathematics knowledge can be a user of it. Perhaps like me, they want to become better at formulating posts, because they think writing questions and answers is valuable to their learning and life. If their posts are deleted without giving constructive, specific feedback on what actionable steps they can take to improve their posts, then they cannot benefit from the app and will not use it.

If their questions really lack words, then the message could be "add more words, because bla bla bla", so they can add more words and the post is improved in quality. At the moment the message is "deleted", and when you make an edit to the post according what you believe might be a good improvement, there is no feedback, so how do you edit the post to make it undeleted? Stack Exchange supports editing of posts and if you edit your posts they should be undeleted, but they are not, even when you edit them, and you don't know what or how to edit.

@AttilaVajda 1) You don't seem aware of the fact that the rules for downvotes and deletions change between questions and answers. I won't be teaching you those any more than what I have already written. 2) This is a Q&A site, id est a site where userA has a problem and userB, who knows the answer and can explain it, solves it. Just like there are ways to misuse the action of walking down a street, there are ways to misuse this site, and you've been listing a few. Writing subpar answers in hope of learning from other people's corrections is one, and it should be penalized, not encouraged.

If you order a steak well done, and it comes to you rare, you can send it back and ask them to improve it by cooking it a little more. If you order a steak well done, and they bring you a lump of coal, you just get up and leave – there's no point in suggesting ways to improve a lump of coal to make it a well done steak. Your answer, Attila, was a lump of coal. There was no point suggesting ways to improve it.

Y'know, stripped of unnecessary details, at its heart this is a "require people to comment before down voting" feature request. I'm lousy at search here, but surely someone can find a duplicate for this?

I would like to improve my posts, as I did make effort to do so. There is no constructive feedback when you improve posts. Improvements to deleted posts don't seem to recover the post and there is no clear feedback to improvements.
Do you suggest, that when posts are not good enough according to your standards, the solution is to downvote, delete, penalise, and assume the author's contribution is somehow malicious? You also seem to be suggesting that on this site it helps if you make clear that the post is worthless.

This does not seem to be in line with a collaborative question and answer site for "students of mathematics at all levels". Mathematics related posts will often have a logical structure similar to those of computer programs, so it is appropriate to edit and improve mathematical arguments over time.

In fact I believe one of the points of learning mathematics is this process of constructing logical arguments, which involves a lot of making mistakes, and not yet seeing the flaws of your arguments. This is similar to how you might write a program in Python, and be unaware of certain aspects of it.
The evolution of posts is a core feature of Stack Exchange, and to me this lack of constructive feedback and difficulty recovering deleted posts is a user experience, accessibility issue that leads to exclusion.

This site is not here to teach you how to do mathematics.

"Students of mathematics at all levels" implies that users of this site are learners. Also, why would you ask a question if not to learn something? Interestingly posting questions is at the moment subject to the same/similar process of downvotes, deletion, and no clear constructive feedback on recovering questions. So how do you ask a question, let alone answer one, as someone new to mathematics?

I have ideas for the solution: give 5 points for constructive feedback on improving posts, reward 50 to both the author and the person contributing with suggestions when the suggestion is implemented. Now giving feedback, and implementing it is rewarded, and there are people who give constructive feedback for reputation. Offer templates for writing questions and answers.

There is a chatroom:
Helpful Commentary.
(I check it once a week.)

A key thing to realize is that unlike your math classes, where the top goal is improving you abilities to do math, the top goal here on math.se is a good, valid body of math knowledge.
If a user is reviewing answers and only has time to vote to remove what they consider a bad answer, but not to explain how to improve it, they are supposed to go ahead with the vote to remove - that does improve the site.
Of course that can be a bit frustrating for the answerer, so there are chat rooms where they can ask for advice on what's wrong/how to improve, although I'll say that those don't get as much traffic as the main site.
I won't get into the mathematical details of your answer here, but I will say that some people (like me) put more into answering/commenting on a post that appears to have more effort put into it. Your answer could have a lot more explanation (use words!), and I'm not surprised to see a terse-almost-to-the-point-of-being-cryptic answer not get a detailed response.
(Aw heck, if I'm talking about how to improve your answer I should also add: as best as I could understand it, I doubt your approach is valid. You seem to be defining functions to and from sets of intervals, and it's not immediately clear what it means for such maps to be continuous. It can be done, but you'd definitely need to explain that.)

Thank you for your answer Jonathan! They have no time for the post, so they are don't care much about it in the first place, but the user who is making the post has time for it and cares about it. So I think it is not fair that those who don't actually care much about the post enough to provide some feedback that can be implemented, can easily contribute to deleting it. "It requires more words", so you can add some comments as an improvement. Similarly to piece of code, "that function needs to be commented", or "comments are redundant" - so person can improve it. Easy

I'll respond to two points in your comment: First, "fair" is not the goal, "maintaining quality of the site" is. Second, some of the people who voted to close go through dozens, if not hundreds of posts a day. They do not have time+energy to write up a response to every post. If you are looking for a website with the primary goal of getting critiques of your math work, math.se will frequently leave your dissatisfied.

My goal was to help someone who asked a mathematics related question, and I spent a few hours understanding the question and producing a coherent, good answer. I found good insight into the problem and was happy with what I found so I posted it to help the questioner. The main goal is to craft canonical quetions and answers, and that is what takes time and energy. The posts being imperfect and open to feedback and improvement is core part of the process. People who only have time and energy to skim a post and like/unlike should not have much say in the matter or deleting posts.

"Mathematics Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for people studying math at any level and professionals in related fields."
That's mathematics at any level. Users should be supported and guided with constructing posts. Collaboration is very good for mathematics learning, and this is why I use this site.

But even though I make an effort to contribute, I am repeatedly made feel unpleasant, by a UX design feature of the app that supports the habits of people who have no time to spare to suggest improvements, but somehow find time to skim hundreds of posts and click deletion. Interestingly, instead of feedback for improvement, the user is provided with a list of these reviewers names and accounts.

Also, people have the experience of explaining things to new users, and having the new user absolutely refuse to hear and address the points being made. After a while you learn that it's not worth the effort to engage with people who are determined to not learn. I'm done here. Good-bye.

I am user with plenty of time and energy to craft good answers and questions for mathematics. I am not a new user and want to implement suggested improvements into my posts, which I would have done if there were such improvements suggested. There are still none suggested through the Form Review, and all the past improvements I made to past posts were not accepted, nor feedback was provided to my changes. There are always people, who care about explaining things to new users, and this should be supported by the design of the website.

As currently it is, a user who volunteers their time and effort to craft questions and answers is made feel unpleasant to do so, while the app supports a small group of people to discard posts without giving any feedback. The sensible situation would be to reward support and guidance with improvements of posts.

Crafting questions and answers, and giving guidance and help to do so make good questions and answers. Making effort only to skim and click deletion to quickly delete a post without feedback for improvements does not make for good questions and answers. A post could be seen as an MVP, or minimum viable product, which can be further improved according to feedback. If there were constructive feedback given I would be spending my time improving the post. Please implement this feature.

@AttilaVajda "I spent a few hours understanding the question and producing a coherent, good answer." perhaps few hours is not enough? I know some users (me included) spent 2-3 days just to research and write a single answer, making it sure the answer is correct and clear for everyone, not only the asker. As an aside, you mentioned "app" a few times. Are you referring this site as a "web app", or are you really using a (non-official) standalone app interacting with this website? Finally, most of us (including moderators) are only users of this site, only staff can implement a new feature.

@AndrewT. it is inspiring that you spend so much time contributing! I meant app as Stack Exchange is similar to other products with ux and accessibility features.

It seems "users cannot improve" is based on the assumption of fixed mindset.
For learning it is better to adopt a growth mindset, which is in harmony with the findings of modern neuroscience research on learning. If you believe in a growth mindset, then users can and do learn, because our brains are plastic throughout the lifespan.
